# why ffmpeg is not working in new installation

Tags: ffmpeg

I was working on live encoding from FFmpeg from last few days. One day I re-installed my OS and tried to run FFmpeg commands again after configuration. My publish points get in starting but could not started. Why? Am I missing any configuration required?

The command I am trying to run is:

```
ffmpeg -y -re -i D:\video2.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -f ismv -threads 0 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -profile:v baseline -map 0:v -b:v:0 800k http://localhost/PPS/PublishPoint.isml/Streams(Encode
r1)
```

Output what I got in command prompt is:

```
ffmpeg version N-54772-g53c853e Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 16 2013 22:25:42 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 40.100 / 52. 40.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 81.101 /  3. 81.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:\video2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.10.100
  Duration: 00:00:12.12, start: 0.072562, bitrate: 945 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 704x396 [
SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 882 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64
 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[libx264 @ 00000000047e0860] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000000047e0860] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 00000000047e0860] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 00000000047e0860] 264 - core 135 r2345 f0c1c53 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 r
ef=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=6 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyi
nt=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=30 rc=abr mbtree=1
 bitrate=800 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1
:1.00
Output #0, ismv, to 'http://localhost/My_SSMN_PPS/saturday.isml/Streams(Encoder1
)':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.12.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 7
04x396 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 800 kb/s, 10000k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   13 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       2kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=2 dro
frame=   29 fps= 29 q=0.0 size=       2kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=2 dro
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error
```

Advanced Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the `av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error` message if you output to a local file?

Comment: Yes... with local file and webcam also.

Comment: I meant as an output.

Comment: I am doing encoding to my publish point which is on my local server, and format is ismv...
(http://localhost/PPS/PublishPoint.isml/Streams(Encoder1))
please see the command..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my devices as I was using HD Webcam replaced with simple devices and It worked fine.
So, I found one solution of this problem but can't say it is ideal.

Thanks.